# Why does my clojure.core.logic nonmember function return two values?

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

I'm trying to implement the opposite of `membero` in `clojure.core.logic`, but it's returning two values instead of one. Otherwise, it works fine (returns nothing when the value is in the list, and something when it is not).

```
(defne nonmembero
  "A relation where l is a collection, such that l does not contain x"
  [x l]
  ([_ ()])
  ([_ [head]]
     (!= x head))
  ([_ [head . tail]]
     (!= x head)
     (nonmembero x tail)))
```

Example runs:

```
user> (run* [x] (nonmembero 1 [2 3 4 5]))
(_0 _0)
user> (run* [x] (nonmembero 1 [2 3 1 4 5]))
()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the second pattern i.e the `[_ [head]`. This is causing a new branch in search space of core.logic engine and hence leads to the 2 output. The last pattern i.e `[head . tail]` is enough to handle the case where you have only one element in the list. Now  your solution becomes:

```
(defne nonmembero
  "A relation where l is a collection, such that l does not contain x"
  [x l]
  ([_ ()])
  ([_ [head . tail]]
     (!= x head)
     (nonmembero x tail)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with the code above. It finds a solution for the following

```
(run* [q](== q 1)(nonmembero q [1 2 3]))  =>  (1)
```

The following gives the expected result

```
(run* [q](== q 1)(nonmembero2 q [1 2 3]))  => ()
```

where nonmembero2 is

```
(defn nonmembero2
  [x l]
  (fresh [h t]
    (conde
      [(== l ())]
      [(conso h t l)
       (!= x h)
       (nonmembero2 x t)])))
```